# WPF DataGrid Virtualizations loses cell layout

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, virtualization

I have a custom styled datagrid with only two columns. The second column is a "DataGridTemplateColumn" with a Grid containing also a custom styled textbox and an Image. I created an "IsValid" Dependency Property in the TextBox, that changes it's backgournd color and border brush depending on bound object's property value. The image changes it's source depending on the IsValid property of the object through a DataTrigger

The textbox basically does some work everytime the user pushes enter in it and sets the IsValid property in the object to true, false or null (of course, through the notifypropertychanged in the object, the changes are reflected on the textbox and image).

Now my problem: When a lot of rows are displayed in the datagrid (somewhere between 100 and a 1000) if I disable RowVirtualization, the vertical scroll gets very slow, but if I leave it on, the new row being generated comes with wrong background color, and the old ones lose their changed layout

Here's the xaml for the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Margin="2"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          Style="{StaticResource dDataGrid2}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          MaxHeight="750"
          EnableRowVirtualization="False"
          SelectionChanged="dgData_SelectionChanged"
          Loaded="dgData_Loaded">

  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource dDataGridRow}">
      <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
                   Handler="Row_Click" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Static fields:FieldNameList.ProductCode}}"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=ProductCode}"
                        Width="auto"
                        MinWidth="160"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Static fields:FieldNameList.Product}}"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=ProductDescription}"
                        Width="*"
                        IsReadOnly="True" />

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Código SNC"
                            Width="120">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Name="gridSNCCode">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <txt:DTextBox Grid.Column="0"
                          x:Name="txtSNCCode"
                          PreviewKeyUp="txtSNCCode_PreviewKeyUp"
                          TextChanged="DTextBox_TextChanged"
                          Text="{Binding Path=PHC_CPOC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsValid="{Binding Path=IsPHC_CPOC_Valid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          NumericOnly="True"
                          SelectAllOnFocus="true" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1"
                   Name="imgValidation"
                   Width="16"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="3 0" />
          </Grid>
          <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPHC_CPOC_Valid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Value="{x:Null}">
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Visibility"
                      Value="Collapsed" />
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Source"
                      Value="{x:Null}" />
              <Setter TargetName="gridSNCCode"
                      Property="ToolTip"
                      Value="" />
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPHC_CPOC_Valid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Visibility"
                      Value="Visible" />
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Source"
                      Value="pack://application:,,,/SAFT2PHC;component/Resources/Images/Success48.png" />
              <Setter TargetName="gridSNCCode"
                      Property="ToolTip"
                      Value="Código SNC Válido" />
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPHC_CPOC_Valid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Visibility"
                      Value="Visible" />
              <Setter TargetName="imgValidation"
                      Property="Source"
                      Value="pack://application:,,,/SAFT2PHC;component/Resources/Images/delete2-48.png" />
              <Setter TargetName="gridSNCCode"
                      Property="ToolTip"
                      Value="Código SNC Inválido" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is the c# code

```
public ObservableCollections<ProductObj> Products { get; set; }

public MyWindow(List<ProductObj> products)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Products = new ObservableCollection(products);
    this.dgData.ItemsSource = this.Products;
}
```

How can I get a good DataGrid performance and not losing the cells updated layout??

I've tried with Items.Refresh() but it doesn't work...

Thanks

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your XAML to place each attribute on a new line.  The amount of horizontal scrolling required was rather excessive.

Comment: Thanks... didn't notice that, it does get easier to read